# CommonAppData in vbscript

Tags: windows, winapi, vbscript, windows-shell, special-folders

A customer's application "AppName" has its configuration files stored in CommonAppData.

- Under Windows XP that is `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\AppName`
- Under Windows Vista that is `C:\ProgramData\AppName`

How do I get the correct foldername with VBScript?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Const CommonAppData = &H23&  ' the second & denotes a long integer '

Set objShell  = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(CommonAppData)

Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self

MsgBox objFolderItem.Name & ": " & objFolderItem.Path
```

The MSDN holds a page that lists the other [Shell Special Folder Constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774096(VS.85).aspx).

This page is nice, too: [Enumerating Special Folders](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/guide/sas_fil_higv.mspx?mfr=true), part of the Microsoft Windows 2000 Scripting Guide. (Link is now defunct, but [the Internet Archive still has a copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20090403061459/http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/guide/sas_fil_higv.mspx).)