# Where should I store application specific settings?

Tags: vb6, windows-7, windows-xp, settings

I've been asked to update a VB6 application that's been running on WinXP for the last 6 years.  The client wants to use Windows 7. Up until now, the app stored its settings in an INI file located in the application directory.  One key difference between XP and 7 is that you can't write to `C:\Program Files\AppFolder` anymore.

I am trying to figure out where on the file system should I store settings?  Given that the application is still required to run on WinXP, I am kind of confused.

On WinXP, I have the following:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\profilename\Application Data
C:\Documents and Settings\profilename\Local Settings\Application Data
```

On Windows 7, I have the following:

```
C:\Users\profilename\AppData\Local
C:\Users\profilename\AppData\LocalLow
C:\Users\profilename\AppData\Roaming
```

Each one of these folders have subfolders that seem to store settings/files for various products

So 2 questions:

1. Given all these folders, where do I store my settings?
2. I am assuming that there is a nifty Windows API call that would give me the proper location of this folder.  And I am hoping it works on both XP and 7.  Is my assumption correct?  If so, a link would be much appreciated.

Comment: +1 But try not to think of it as a key difference. You probably shouldn't have been writing to the shared "Program Files" folder even on pre-Vista versions of Windows.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a number of special folders you can use, on XP/Vista/Windows 7:

- The `CSIDL_APPDATA` folder is the one you will likely be most interested in. Data stored here is available to roaming users at whatever machine they log in to. This is the best place to store simple configuration data. All users have write access to this (and the last) folder. Note that none of the above folders are for user-generated data! That would properly belong under the My Documents hierarchy.
- **EDIT:** As Cody Gray suggests in the comments, also consider `CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA` for application data that will always be local to the current machine, but is set aside on a per user basis. The data in this folder is not available on a roaming basis, so it should be data that the user will likely not miss if they log in to a different machine.

I shamelessly copied the explanation above from a [good article](http://vb.mvps.org/articles/vsm20090119.pdf) by Karl Peterson, explaining this for VB6 programmers. Karl also has a [ready-to-use class](http://vb.mvps.org/samples/SysFolders) that will help you find the directories, but IMHO he's overcomplicated things this time. [Bob Riemersma has a better way in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054802/commonappdata-in-vb6/3073836#3073836), using the [Shell object](https://web.archive.org/web/20120828005214/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774094(VS.85).aspx), as below. **EDIT** Bob's comment below explains why it's best to use *late binding* for this rather than *early binding*.

```
Const ssfCOMMONAPPDATA = &H23 
Const ssfLOCALAPPDATA = &H1c
Const ssfAPPDATA = &H1a
Dim strAppData As String 
 
strAppData = _ 
    CreateObject("Shell.Application").NameSpace(ssfAPPDATA).Self.Path
```

In my opinion it's fine to [continue to use INI files](https://web.archive.org/web/20080229181457/http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2007/11/26/6523907.aspx) in these directories.

Comment: +1 `CSIDL_APPDATA` is the folder you should probably be using. However, for settings that should not roam with the user, consider using `CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA`.

Comment: I want to add the caveat that while it might seem clever to add a reference to the Shell library and use early binding (plus all of the Shell Special Folder constants come along for the ride) Microsoft has not been careful about preserving binary compatibility for Shell32.dll's COM interface. Stick with late-binding on this one, your program won't be calling this in a tight loop anyway so performance is no issue.

Comment: @Bob Good to know.  I was actually wondering why Mark posted a late bound example and was planning to use early binding.  That would have been a fun error to debug.

Comment: Note that it is safe enough to reference Shell Controls and Automation to get these special folder constants without hand-coding Consts.  Just avoid As New here and declare any reference variable As Object.

Answer (score 7):

See the question "[Does Microsoft have a best practices document regarding the storage of app data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507923/does-microsoft-have-a-best-practices-document-regarding-the-storage-of-app-data-v)" for some helpful info.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you just save your settings in Windows Registry?
That's very easy. Using SaveSeting and GetSetting is much easier than creating INI file.
And there is no trouble in compatibility, from WinNT to Windows 8.