# How To Use the SHGetKnownFolderPath Function from Vb6

Tags: winapi, windows-7, vb6, known-folders

I am currently adding Windows 7 support to an existing Vb6 project and I have ran into a problem with locating special folder paths using SHGetFolderPath which is not supported on Windows versions starting with Vista.  I know I should use SHGetKnownFolderPath but I cannot  find a good example implementing using SHGetKnownFolderPath API call in VB6.

Comment: I finally found an example.  http://en.kioskea.net/faq/951-vba-vb6-my-documents-environment-variables

Comment: Similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273424/where-should-i-store-application-specific-settings/4275821

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easier to use the [Shell object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774094%28VS.85%29.aspx)
Late binding is advised because Microsoft haven't been careful about compatibility with this object.

```
Const ssfCOMMONAPPDATA = &H23 
Const ssfLOCALAPPDATA = &H1c
Const ssfAPPDATA = &H1a
Dim strAppData As String 

strAppData = _ 
    CreateObject("Shell.Application").NameSpace(ssfAPPDATA).Self.Path
```

Comment: id values for NameSpace https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774096(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Using the code the the following this article [vba/vb6](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/951-vba-vb6-my-documents-environment-variables)
Declaring the API call at the top of module WINAPI32.bas

```
Private Declare Function SHGetSpecialFolderLocation Lib "shell32.dll" _
                    (ByVal hwndOwner As Long, ByVal nFolder As Long, _
                     pidl As ITEMIDLIST) As Long
Private Declare Function SHGetPathFromIDList Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "SHGetPathFromIDListA" _
                        (ByVal pidl As Long, ByVal pszPath As String) As Long
Private Type SHITEMID
    cb As Long
    abID As Byte
End Type
Private Type ITEMIDLIST
    mkid As SHITEMID
End Type
```

Added a new public function:

```
Public Function SHGetSpecialFolderLocationVB(ByVal lFolder As Long) As String
    Dim lRet As Long, IDL As ITEMIDLIST, sPath As String

    lRet = SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(100&, lFolder, IDL)
    If lRet = 0 Then
        sPath = String$(512, chr$(0))
        lRet = SHGetPathFromIDList(ByVal IDL.mkid.cb, ByVal sPath)
        SHGetSpecialFolderLocationVB = Left$(sPath, InStr(sPath, chr$(0)) - 1)
    Else
        SHGetSpecialFolderLocationVB = vbNullString
    End If
End Function
```

Added a new function to check for Windows versions Vista or higher

```
Public Function IsVistaOrHigher() As Boolean
    Dim osinfo As OSVERSIONINFO
    Dim retvalue As Integer
    Dim bVista As Boolean

    bVista = False

    osinfo.dwOSVersionInfoSize = 148
    osinfo.szCSDVersion = Space$(128)
    retvalue = GetVersionExA(osinfo)

    If osinfo.dwPlatformId = 2 Then
        If osinfo.dwMajorVersion >= 6 Then
            bVista = True
        End If
    End If
    IsVistaOrHigher = bVista
End Function
```

Altered the previous method calling SHGetFolderPath

```
Public Function SHGetFolderPathVB(ByVal lFolder As Long) As String
    Dim path As String
    If IsVistaOrHigher() Then
        SHGetFolderPathVB = SHGetSpecialFolderLocationVB(lFolder)
    Else
        path = Space$(MAX_PATH)
        SHGetFolderPath 0, lFolder, 0, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, path
        SHGetFolderPathVB = Left(path, InStr(path, vbNullChar) - 1)
    End If
End Function
```

Works great!

Comment: If won't work so great when dwMajorVersion > 6. You can just test osinfo.dwMajorVersion>=6 and not even bother with the dwPlatformId test because Windows 9x stopped at dwMajorVersion=4.

Answer (score 2):

Using `SHGetFolderPath` from `shfolder.dll` just works fine under Vista and Win7:

```
Private Declare Function SHGetFolderPath Lib "shfolder" Alias "SHGetFolderPathA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal csidl As Long, ByVal hToken As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal szPath As String) As Long
```

Then declare an enum on those `CSIDL_Xxx` constants:

```
Public Function GetSpecialFolder(ByVal eType As MySpecialFolderType) As String
    GetSpecialFolder = String(1000, 0)
    Call SHGetFolderPath(0, eType, 0, 0, GetSpecialFolder)
    GetSpecialFolder = Left$(GetSpecialFolder, InStr(GetSpecialFolder, Chr$(0)) - 1)
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

A very late answer. But it actually shows how to use `SHGetKnownFolderPath` in x64 VBA and no workarounds to avoid it.

I used this German source: https://dbwiki.net/wiki/VBA_Tipp:_Spezielle_Verzeichnisse_ermitteln

The solution given there doesn’t work on x64 Office. So I changed it. Calling a native DLL from VBA requires

- Usage of the new keyword `PtrSafe`.
- Usage of `LongPtr` instead of `Long` for all pointers.
- Conversion of VBA strings to `LongPtr` objects by  means of the function `StrPtr`.
- Calling the Unicode version of the DLL, usually marked with a “W.”

Code:

```
Public Const FOLDERID_ProgramFiles1  As String = "{905E63B6-C1BF-494E-B29C-65B732D3D21A}"

Public Type GUID
 Data1 As Long
 Data2 As Integer
 Data3 As Integer
 Data4(7) As Byte
End Type

Public Const S_OK As Long = 0
Public Const WIN32_NULL As Long = 0

Public Declare PtrSafe Sub CoTaskMemFree Lib "ole32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr)

Public Declare PtrSafe Function CLSIDFromString Lib "ole32" ( _
  ByVal lpszGuid As LongPtr, _
  ByRef pGuid As GUID) As Long

Public Declare PtrSafe Function lstrlenW Lib "kernel32" ( _
 ByVal lpString As LongPtr) As Long

Public Declare PtrSafe Function SHGetKnownFolderPath Lib "shell32" ( _
  ByRef rfid As GUID, _
  ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
  ByVal hToken As Long, _
  ByRef pszPath As LongPtr) As Long

Public Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" ( _
 ByVal Destination As LongPtr, _
 ByVal Source As LongPtr, _
 ByVal length As Long)

Public Function GetBstrFromWideStringPtr(ByVal lpwString As LongPtr) As String
  Dim length As Long

  If (lpwString) Then length = lstrlenW(lpwString)
  If (length) Then
    GetBstrFromWideStringPtr = Space$(length)
    CopyMemory StrPtr(GetBstrFromWideStringPtr), lpwString, length * 2
  End If
End Function

Public Function GetKnownFolder(ByVal KnownFolderID As String) As String
'Returns empty String on any error.
  Dim ref As GUID
  Dim pszPath As LongPtr

  If (CLSIDFromString(StrPtr(KnownFolderID), ref) = S_OK) Then
    If (SHGetKnownFolderPath(ref, 0, WIN32_NULL, pszPath) = S_OK) Then
      GetKnownFolder = GetBstrFromWideStringPtr(pszPath)
      CoTaskMemFree pszPath
    End If
  End If
End Function

Sub TestKnownFolder()
 MsgBox GetKnownFolder(FOLDERID_ProgramFiles1)
End Sub
```

At the above link, you can find all `FOLDERID_Blah` strings.