# Getting rid of user specific file path

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro to paste text files into an Excel document, I have the following code which starts with the users name. Is a there a way I can make it so anyone can use the macro without having to make it for each person?

```vb
Sub Sample()
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Users\johnsmith\Wfilepath.txt", Destination:=Range("$A$1") _
        )
        .Name = "Sample"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `Environ("USERPROFILE")` might be helpful.

Comment: The `Environ` method is good but can theoretically fail if the user has messed with the environment variables. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75102471/12287457) if you want to learn everything about getting special folder paths on windows in VBA.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Environ("USERPROFILE") as below:

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim filePath As String
    filePath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Wfilepath.txt"
    
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= "TEXT;" & filePath, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .... YOUR CODE HERE
    End With
End Sub
```