# Unable to access file in OneDrive

Tags: excel, vba, dns

I'm using a computer with Windows 11 Home, the user I’m trying to interact with is on a domain and is using Windows 11 Professional. I have created some VBA code inside of Excel that looks for a file on OneDrive. I can access the file fine, but my user gets an error message, file not found. My debug messages tell me that we are both using the same path name to the file. So, why can’t the user access the file?

Note that we are both at work on the same domain, in the same location, on the same network and that we both have permissions to access the file. The only difference between our environments is that the user machine is joined to the domain and mine is not.

The VBA program accesses a file and copies it to the workbook. The expectation is that the file would be found and the copy would be successfully.  This is how I've constructed the path to the file. Which is exactly how it appears on both the Home and the Professional machines. This is from a debug statement inside my VBA code.

`C:\Users\Comp03\OneDrive -WTServices\WTS Shared\Billing By Month\March Billing\March 2024 Billing\Excel Files\WC-Auto-2024-03-05.xlsx`

Running VBA code in the domain is not an issue because there are other workbooks using it without issue.    They just don't require that file be accessed as I'm doing.

Has anyone else seen this issue and what was the resolution?

Comment: `My debug messages tell me that we are both using the same path name to the file.` Can you post the output of both debug statements?

Comment: This: [Obtain any user's Desktop path if OneDrive is a factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75102370/obtain-any-users-desktop-path-if-onedrive-is-a-factor) may help you.

Comment: The path returned on both the domain and non-domain machines looked like this -- C:\Users\Admin.WTSLT07\OneDrive - WTS\WTS Shared\Billing By Month\March Billing\March 2024 Billing\Excel Files\file.xlsx

Comment: Great article but I have VBA code that does the OneDrive translation within Excel and it works perfectly