# When removing the Config.json file from the ProgramData, showing "Permission Denied" in C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, c++17

I am trying to remove the config.json file from program data, But with the below code it is showing "Permission Denied".

```
int main()
{
        std::string f_strConfigFile = "C:\\ProgramData\\TestApplication\\TestConfig.json";

        std::string l_strFileContents;
        std::ifstream l_ifConfigFileStream(f_strConfigFile.c_str());
        if (l_ifConfigFileStream)
        {
            l_ifConfigFileStream.seekg(0, ios::end);
            size_t l_szFileSize = (size_t)l_ifConfigFileStream.tellg();
            l_ifConfigFileStream.seekg(0, ios::beg);
            char* l_chBuffer = new char[l_szFileSize + 1];
            memset(l_chBuffer, 0, l_szFileSize + 1);
            l_ifConfigFileStream.read(l_chBuffer, l_szFileSize + 1);
            l_strFileContents.assign(l_chBuffer);
            delete[] l_chBuffer;
        }
        l_ifConfigFileStream.close();

        if (l_strFileContents.empty())
        {
            l_strFileContents.assign("{}");
        }
        if (remove(f_strConfigFile.c_str()) != 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to remove the file" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Removed the file" << endl;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

could any one suggest how to remove the config file?

Comment: If you read [the `remove` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/remove-wremove?view=msvc-170) you will see that it sets the `errno` variable on failure. What is the value of `errno`? If you use e.g. `perror` to print the an error message, what does it say?

Comment: And since you have the C++17 tag, then why not use [`std::filesystem::remove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/remove) function instead?

Comment: You should not hardcode the path to ProgramData, use the known folder API.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, Thank you for your suggestion. I tried by printing errno. It is showing "Permission denied"

Comment: You should update your question with the "Permission denied" return value rather than add it to the comments.

Comment: Hi @AndrewTruckle, I didn't consider the elevated admin rights. when i tried manually, it is asking admin rights to delete the file. How to provide elevated permissions when removing the file from the code?

Comment: That is a separate question entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Common Application Data Folder

There might not be any issue with your code in itself. Although I stand by all the suggestions made in the comments. They will make your code more efficient.

In the comments you said:

> I tried by printing errno. It is showing "Permission denied".

**Administrator** rights are needed to **save** files to the common application data folder (`%programdata%`). Whilst all users have **read access**.

If you want to **delete**, you would need **elevated administrator rights**.

Run your executable with **elevation** and I bet it will delete the file.

The principles of the above are also discussed here in one of the answers ([How to write to the common Application Data folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10507233/2287576)).

---

### Administrator Rights

You also asked in the comments:

> How to provide elevated permissions when removing the file from the code?

This is really a different question. For what it's worth, in my application I have a dedicated executable just for the administrative tasks. And I spawn it with elevated rights. The button on my dialog has a Shield to indicate it will need to run with elevation.

Of course you can right-click an executable and run with elevation. But programatically? If it is even possible? I would start a new question for that.

---

To address your original question, you need administrative rights to delete froms from that special folder.