# File creation by using Vb script

Tags: vbscript

I need a VB script which will create text file named "listitem" in C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\secon\smartapp
up to C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\ we can make it as 'CommonAppDataFolder'

Any one knows about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, let's see if I can remember how to do this...

```
Dim fso 'As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim stream 'As Scripting.TextStream

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Check that the secon folder exists
If fso.FolderExists("C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\secon") Then
Else
    fso.CreateFolder("C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\secon")
End If

'Check that the smartapp folder exists
If fso.FolderExists("C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\secon\smartapp") Then
Else
    fso.CreateFolder("C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\secon\smartapp")
End If

'Create the file as ASCII text, overwrite it if it already exists
Set stream = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\secon\smartapp\listitem.txt", true, false)

'Close it neatly
stream.Close

'Clean up
Set stream = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
```

Comment: i need an optimized solution by using CommonAppData

Comment: this wl work fine,but i need an optimized solution by using CommonAppData

Answer (score 1):

Here're some tips for you:

- To obtain the CommonAppData path programmatically, use the [`Shell.Namespace(35)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774085.aspx) method. (35 is the folder id according to the [ShellSpecialFolderConstants Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774096.aspx).) See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295303/commonappdata-in-vbscript) for an example.
- To concatenate two paths, use the [`FileSystemObject.BuildPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0z2z1zt.aspx) method.
- To create text files, you can use the [`FileSystemObject.CreateTextFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5t9b5c0c.aspx) method.

Hope you can manage the rest yourself. :)